# how to configure htaccess to show dynamic second subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, virtual, subdomain

I have this goal : to be able to redirect or show a specific page for a virtual second subdomain like :
virtual.hotels.sample.com

and I have these htaccess rules written out

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^hotels.sample\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?hotels.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://hotels.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cheap-hotels-country/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?country=$1&custom=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cheap-hotels-city/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?city=$1&custom=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cheap-hotels-country/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cheap-hotels-city/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?city=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^find-cheap-hotels-country/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index2.php?country=$1&custom=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^find-cheap-hotels-city/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index2.php?city=$1&custom=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^find-cheap-hotels-country/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index2.php?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^find-cheap-hotels-city/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/?$ index2.php?city=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.hotels.sample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www)\.hotels.sample.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /home/sample/public_html/index.php [L]
```

but of course its not working. Hope someone could help me out!!

Comment: Could you pleas elaborate on what is required to be done? Provide an example as well. Thnx

Comment: well i needed for example somename.hotels.sample.com to show the index at hotels.sample.com .. basically like that..

Comment: If that's it -- then why don't you simply point subdomain to the same folder as main domain? If you want something different, then please describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^hotels.asia\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?hotels.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://hotels.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please correct  it!!! assume your host is : `virtual.hotels.sample.com`, So it will redirects to `http://hotels.sample.com/` then this part NEVER will execute:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.hotels.sample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www)\.hotels.sample.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /home/sample/public_html/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @maida barrientos look!  RewriteRule operates on URL(e.g forum/private.php?do=showpm&pmid=54996)  NOT the physical path on server(/home/sample/public_html/index.php)!  if you want to JUST show index of http://hotels.sample.com/ , I think your change is enough!(RewriteRule (.*) http://hotels.sample.com/$1 [R=301,L] won't show index page, it will change the host with same path & query string!)

Comment: @maida barrientos The first part will do what you want! there is no need to second part(It will not execute)!

Comment: hmm..i think it should be done via server side by wildcarding the vhost